# Trying to find a good writeup of the challenges of localisation/translation

Tags: localization, translation, multilingual

About a month ago, I came across an amazing blog post about the challenges of translating software, where the author had a theoretical program to translate into 5 or so different languages, and the difficulties inherent due to the completely different structures of each language. I seem to remember it was also doing this in the context of pointing out the failings of gettext.

The author talked about a sentence along the lines of 'There were x file(s) renamed' and how that differed according to english, italian, russian etc, in particular against the pluralisation and how that changed the structure of the sentence.

My google fu is not strong enough to find this article again, I dont suppose anyone was smarter than me and thought to bookmark it?

Comment: Can you check your browser history?

Comment: I totally didn't think of that! no seriously, it was on a different computer. if i could have i would have.

Comment: so much to find on that topic, and even good solutions for the proplem of pluralisation. but as you haven't requested something helpful for a certain language...a tricky task, sir.

Comment: i know its a vague question, if you had read the article you would recognise which one i was talking about i think. It was a general work through of the problems of translation rather than a tutorial on how to translate in language x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found It. (Finally)

[A Localisation Horror Story: It Could Happen To You.](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Locale-Maketext/lib/Locale/Maketext/TPJ13.pod#A_Localization_Horror_Story%3a_It_Could_Happen_To_You)